# Trying to install Composer on OSX 10.9

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install Composer on OSX 10.9 following the instructions from getcomposer.org using this command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local
```

Result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write bundled     cacert.pem to: /Users/aaron.rossano/.composer/cacert.pem' in -:402
Stack trace:
#0 -(112): installComposer(false, '/usr/local', 'composer.phar', false, false, false)
#1 -(14): process(Array)
#2 {main}
thrown in - on line 402
```

Comment: It's probably a rights problem. Try relaunching this command with sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, try downloading an older version of the Composer installer from GitHub. Simply replace the curl endpoint to a previous state of the installer file, e.g.:

```
curl -sS https://raw.github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/c6fedc418e1f80347724cf1bc3e86b607ac3ba30/web/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local
```

Note: This is an older version of the installer only, not Composer itself. It'll download the latest version of Composer.

Additionally, to execute as superuser:

```
sudo sh -c "curl -sS https://raw.github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/c6fedc418e1f80347724cf1bc3e86b607ac3ba30/web/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local"
```

Comment: thanks jacob. i tried with and without 'sudo' but it didn't work.
`Could not create file /usr/local/composer.phar: 
fopen(/usr/local/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/usr/local/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: @Aaron Sorry, so, unless you wrapped the command in a shell with root permissions, `sudo` will only affect the downloading of the package (`curl`) and not the execution (`php`). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug introduced on 3/9/14. I sent a pull request to fix it:

https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/pull/62

In the mean time, just manually create a .composer folder in your home directory.

Comment: thanks for the answer jimbojsb. i get the following error after creating the .composer directory in /Users/aaron.rossano/ error: `All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Could not create file /usr/local/composer.phar: fopen(/usr/local/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/usr/local/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: `.composer` folder? Mac doesn't allow me to create says its for system only.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug. **Finaly achieve to run it** by using **`sudo -s`** and then re run `sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`.

Just posting this in case this could help someone.